# Sorting XML in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I have looked at the documentation on sorting XML with Groovy

```
def records = new XmlParser().parseText(XmlExamples.CAR_RECORDS)
assert ['Royale', 'P50', 'HSV Maloo'] == records.car.sort{ it.'@year'.toInteger() }.'@name'
```

but what I am trying to do is sort the XML and then return the xml string sorted. I know I can completely rebuild the XML after i am done sorting.

I know I can run an XML Transformation on the XML to get it sorted

```
def factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
def transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)))
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(input)), new StreamResult(System.out))
```

BUT I was looking for some Groovy magic to make it easier for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is to replace directly the list of `car` within the `records`. Not sure if more magic exists!

```
records.value = records.car.sort{ it.'@year'.toInteger() }
println XmlUtil.serialize(records)
```

Comment: will give it a try... I found a solution but I think this is easier.