# Sort XML child nodes by date field in Groovy Script

Tags: xml, sorting, groovy, sap-cpi

My XML is like below... I need to sort *EmpJob* nodes under *jobInfoNav* by startDate element. I tried below codes and followed below logs, it doesn't give any error but list is not sorting. Please help.

I am using this groovy script in SAP CPI.

**XML**:

```
<PerPerson>
<PerPerson>
  <employmentNav>
    <EmpEmployment>
      <jobInfoNav>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10193</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>SP</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-09-20T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10196</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>RP</eventReason>
          <startDate>2019-04-14T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10186</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>RL</eventReason>
          <startDate>2019-08-19T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10203</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>HN</eventReason>
          <startDate>2018-05-02T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10193</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>ZC</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-03-08T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10193</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>EC</eventReason>
          <startDate>2018-09-23T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
      </jobInfoNav>
    </EmpEmployment>
  </employmentNav>
</PerPerson>
<PerPerson>
  <employmentNav>
    <EmpEmployment>
      <jobInfoNav>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10203</event>
          <userId>abc789</userId>
          <eventReason>HN</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-06-22T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10193</event>
          <userId>abc789</userId>
          <eventReason>ZC</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-06-22T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10180</event>
          <userId>abc789</userId>
          <eventReason>LD</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-06-24T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
      </jobInfoNav>
    </EmpEmployment>
  </employmentNav>
</PerPerson>
<PerPerson>
  <employmentNav>
    <EmpEmployment>
      <jobInfoNav>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10193</event>
          <userId>abc999</userId>
          <eventReason>SP</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-08-30T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10206</event>
          <userId>abc999</userId>
          <eventReason>RN</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-08-24T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10203</event>
          <userId>abc999</userId>
          <eventReason>HC</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-01-21T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
      </jobInfoNav>
    </EmpEmployment>
  </employmentNav>
```

**Groovy script**:

```
   def xml =  new XmlSlurper().parseText(body)     //use of of these depending on which code you are using
   def xml =  new XmlParser().parseText(body)   //use of of these depending on which code you are using

     XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {                                           
PerPerson{
    PerPerson {
        employmentNav{
            EmpEmployment{
                jobInfoNav{
                     xml.jobInfoNav[0]
                     .children()
                     .sort { Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss", it.startDate.text()) }
                     .each { e ->
                         EmpJob {
                                event(e.event.text())
                                userId(e.userId.text())
                                eventReason(e.eventReason.text())
                                startDate(e.startDate.text())
                                }     
                                        
                            }
                        }
   
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
    )
 
    message.setBody(XmlUtil.serialize(xml))
```

also tried below

```
// xml.PerPerson.employmentNav.EmpEmployment.jobInfoNav.EmpJob.sort(true) {it.attribute('startDate')}
```

also tried below code

```
 new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {                                                                    // not working
    xml.PerPerson.PerPerson.EmpEmploymentNav.EmpEmployment.jobInfoNav[0].children().sort { Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss", it.startDate.text()) }
                     .each { e ->
                         EmpJob {
                                event(e.event.text())
                                userId(e.userId.text())
                                eventReason(e.eventReason.text())
                                startDate(e.startDate.text())
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I don't see any errors but EmpJob nodes not sorted. Please help.

followed online threads

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/groovy-user/rNapYFuFl-0

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/API-Functional-Security-Testing/Sorting-XML-response-before-assertion/td-p/107186

[How to sort XML with Groovy using value of Node (Date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675218/how-to-sort-xml-with-groovy-using-value-of-node-date)

[Use Groovy to Sort XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150601/use-groovy-to-sort-xml-file)

[Sorting XML in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558780/sorting-xml-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
def body='''
<PerPerson>
  <employmentNav>
    <EmpEmployment>
      <jobInfoNav>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10206</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>RH</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-10-05T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10186</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>RL</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-03-11T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10203</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>HN</eventReason>
          <startDate>2019-12-16T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10190</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>Z1</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-06-13T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10193</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>ZC</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-03-11T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10189</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>RW</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-06-13T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
        <EmpJob>
          <event>10180</event>
          <userId>abc123</userId>
          <eventReason>FU</eventReason>
          <startDate>2020-04-15T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpJob>
      </jobInfoNav>
    </EmpEmployment>
  </employmentNav>
</PerPerson>
'''

def xml =  new XmlParser().parseText(body)
def jobInfoNav = xml.employmentNav.EmpEmployment.jobInfoNav[0]
//get value - array of child nodes, sort, and set it back
jobInfoNav.value = jobInfoNav.value().sort{ e-> e.startDate.text() }

groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. How to get a reverse of it? I mean its now in ascending order, how to make it as descending?

Comment: Also, this code works when supplied with one user as in question. BUT, if multiple users are supplied with multiple EmpJob nodes for each user then this sorting does NOT work. It won't give error but sorting does not  happen for multiple users xml.

Comment: `sort{a,b-> b.startDate.text() <=> a.startDate.text()}`. And for multiple users - you have to iterate them. I can't guess how XML looks like for multiple users...

Comment: Thank you, it worked too, that's a great help for a newbie/novice in Groovy world. ***Also, edited the xml in my question on how it looks with multiple users. Thanks again.***

Comment: the xml you provided is not valid - there should be a root tag.

Comment: Its in SAP CPI coming out of Successfactor's using https and /odata/v2 request and that's how I see in the message body. I process this exact format in groovy script. Thank you.

Comment: in groovy `XmlParser` can't parse xml like `<a>1</a><a>2</a>` you need a root element like this: `<r> <a>1</a><a>2</a> </r>`

Comment: why can't it consider first <PerPerson> as root tag? `<PerPerson> <PerPerson> details of person 1> </PerPerson><PerPerson> details of person 2></PerPerson><PerPerson> details of person 3></PerPerson></PerPerson>` in this top <PerPerson> behaving as root correct?
I didn't have any issues until now in CPI processing it in groovy or xslt with this type of xml. how can I loop thinking first <PerPerson> as root>?
`def xml =  new XmlParser().parseText(body)
xml.PerPerson.each{ sorting code} --- not working 
xml.PerPerson.PerPerson.each {sorting code} --- not working`
Thank you.

Comment: ah. that quite strange. i thought it was a mistake